# Error: "contains is not a function" in ionic 2

Tags: string, validation, typescript, ionic2, contains

I'm trying to write some codes that check the contains of my input but I don't know why I can't use contains function.

This is my typescript function:

```
checkFnameFunction(name){
    if(name.contains("[a-zA-Z]+") == false && name.length() > 3){
        this.checkFname=true;
        alert("true");
    }else{
        this.checkFname=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply because it doesn't exist: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String (I'm assuming that name is a string, since you didn't specify its type, and thus get the error at compile time rather than runtime)

Comment: So no solution for this issue ?

Comment: The solution is to use a method which exists. Which method? We don't know, since we don't know what you're trying to achieve. How about reading the documentation to find out by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution by using RegExp test

```
checkFnameFunction(name){
    let patt=/^[a-zA-Z]{3,15}$/;
    if(patt.test(name)){
        this.checkFname=true;
    }else{
        this.checkFname=false;
    }
}
```